# Store and Execute Class Method in List<>

Tags: c#

Im adding a GUI to a console app, to learn WPF.
It has a rather long case statement to check input.
My thinkng is convert the switch case to an List based of a class, then use the list to fill the gui and the associated action when the item is clicked.

First stage is to convert a long switch case to a list to store the choices.

```
Console.WriteLine("\nEnter Your Choice [Main]");
Console.WriteLine("1.  Your Name");
Console.WriteLine("2.  Your Age");
case 1:
Program.Helo();
break;
case 2:
Program.getAgeDisplay();
break;
more..........
```

So instead i have a class to create the menu items.
Then i add them to a list;

```
        menuitems.Add(new MenuItem("Your Name", Helo.Program.Helo()));
```

What type do i store the "Helo.Program.Helo()" as?
Should i just store it as text and then can somehow execute it another way?
As its a class method, Can it even be stored in a class ?
I've been learning C# for a week, be gentle.
So far iver tried Object & Type but error on;

```
Error   CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'void' to 'object'
```

SOLUTION:

```
namespace GuiMenu
{
public class Program
{
    public static List<MenuItem> CreateMenu()
    {
        List<MenuItem> menuitems = new List<MenuItem>();
        menuitems.Add(new MenuItem("Your Name", Helo.Program.Helo));
        menuitems.Add(new MenuItem("Your Age"));
        Console.WriteLine(menuitems);
        return menuitems;
    }
    //setup menu class
            public class MenuItem
            {
                private string name;
                private Action action;

                public MenuItem(string name)
                {
                    this.Name = name;
                }

                public MenuItem(string name, Action action) : this(name)
                {
                    this.action = action;
                }

              public string Name   // property  
                {
                    get { return name; }
                    set { name = value; }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i wish Downvoters were forced to comment as to why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is good, but this code:

```
new MenuItem("Your Name", Helo.Program.Helo())
```

Attempts to invoke `Helo.Program.Helo()` and put the result into a `new MenuItem`. But according to your error message, `Helo.Program.Helo` returns `void` so there is no result.

You want to create a `MenuItem` constructor like

```
MenuItem(string, Action) ...
```

and add your methods like:

```
new MenuItem("Your Name", Helo.Program.Helo)
```

Writing a method name without trailing parentheses will create a delegate to the method, not invoke it.

Comment: Thank You! - it makes sense now, delegated Action was the key feature needed.

Answer (score 1):

The "clean" way would be to implement `ICommand` in your ViewModel and submit the current list entry as `CommandParameter` to it. Another way would be to implement a `OnClick` or some event like that to the list entry.

If you still want todo it the way you started it with, your 2nd parameter of `MenuItem` needs to be a `Action` or `Func`.

Comment: Thanks, if you had mentioned the word "Delegate" i probably would of had enough to research more.